# Hosting Node-RED and running “untrusted” flows

Tags: docker, security, node-red

I am currently wondering if it is possible for me to host Node-Red for Users and let them create their own flows that run on my server/in my docker container. This setup would create one docker container per user.

Is it possible to protect against all kinds of attacks that a User could write in a Node-Red function?
Are there other attack vectors that I should be aware of?

Comment: What is the purpose of offering users a Node-RED instance in this environment?

Answer (score 1):

This all comes down to what you expect the user to be able to do in this environment. But there are the following options to control what users can do.

The function node is sandboxed so doesn't have access to the full set of NodeJS APIs and it can not by default `require` extra modules.

You can disable the pallet management feature so users can't install new Node-RED nodes and you can also disable any of the core nodes (e.g. the exec node, or the nodes that access the local filesystem).

So it is possible to significantly reduce the possible attack vectors